# How to deal with an incompletely randomized experiment and LMM?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design

### The Experiment

I am investigating if there are significant differences in crop-yield between the systems (1-6).
The experiment I am working on is nine years old and can be seen as a partially randomized complete **BLOCK** design:

- Each colored replicate represents a different level of the single factor “**system**” and can be seen as the **MAIN-PLOT**.
- Each letter represents a different crop e.g. wheat, corn, clover-grass... The crops are rotated after one year within their **SUB-PLOT** acording to the crop rotation (e.g. next year A becomes B, B becomes C and so on).
- The missing randomization between system 1,2 and 3,4,5,6, is due to regulations and expected neighboring effects of the systemspecific treatments.

[image: Field Experiment Layout]

### The Problem

I came up with a nice lmm which allows me to investigate the effect of system and year on yield with the help of the following paper from [Onofri et al. 2016](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1161030116300399?via=ihub), so to compare all yields from crop A I did this:

```
m1 <- lme(yield ~ system * year, random=~1|Block/Main/Sub)
```

The model works out great and was selected and adjusted with the AIC, **but** my problem is that I am unsure if it is okay to accept the fact that the blocks are not compleatly randomized or if it is forbidden to do so and one has to take it as two seperate trials.

The soil of the field was analyzed beforehand and showed absolutely homogeneous proprietaries in all of the SUB-PLOTS, this and the fact that the reason for the missing randomization (regulations and neighboring effects) can be explained quite well was the reason for me to accept the shown model.

But now I am a bit unsure and would be thankful to hear some expertise of you guys.

Comment: To clarify the thing you're wondering about is if it's okay to have the same order of your main plots for each system in each block? i.e. system order isn't randomized within a block.

Comment: Kind of, as you can see systems 1 and 2 as well as 3,4,5 and 6 are kind of radomized in their part of the block/experiment but 1 or 2 are never in the right side of the field for example, my main conceren is this specific fact: the missing shuffeling of 1 and 2 with 3,4,5 and 6 which has not been done due to the mentioned restrictions.

Comment: Ah, I see— what if you included east-west orientation as a random effect e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6 based on how far to the east a given system/sample was. If it’s non-significant after accounting for the other random effects I’d say it’s fine to leave it out of the model and your design is fine. If it is significant you have to figure out why your system is changing from west to east after accounting for all the other factors. You may need to use a a type 1 sum of squares to preserve the order of the random effects— I.e. you don’t want to remove east-west effect before accounting for the system effect.

Comment: I think adding the distance, or simply the column number as random effect would only give an indication of how mutch of the calculated variance can be explained with it and not if there are significant differences. However I did try both adding it as a random and fixed effect, without finding any significant effects of it on yield, so far so good. The other thing is that I know for sure that system 1,2 have significantly higher yields compared with 3,4,5,6 because of their treatments, the whole reason of this layout and my problem, anyways checking it already helped a bit thanks.

Comment: So if system 1 and 2 produce higher values you'd have to follow up with a pairwise test to show that those groups are significantly different from the rest.

Comment: Yes that's what I did: a post hoc test with tukey adjustment for multiple comparisons and it works out just like I planned. But all that won't solve my initial problem the incomplete randomization. I want to report my findings from the post hoc test but am unsure if I can set up my model like I did with the poor experimental design or if there are better ways.